# ListView and LineraLayout under one ScrollBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I want to create the following layout:

1. Section '1' is a `LinearLayout` which contains an `ImageView` and a `TextView`
2. Section '2' is a `ListView` with customized row layouts.

I want to place both components under a single vertical `ScrollBar`, meaning I don't want the `ScrollBar` only for the `ListView`. Currently I'm achieving the following layout through placing things in a `TableView` but I want functionality like `ListView` items.

[alt text http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/5386/detaili.jpg](http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/5386/detaili.jpg)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can programmatically add 'Section 1' as a **header view** to the ListView using `ListView.addHeaderView(View v)`. See [docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)).

Example code here:

```
View headerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
        R.layout.foo_list_header, null);

mListView = (ListView) findViewById(...);
mListView.addHeaderView(headerView);

setListAdapter(...);
```

Comment: Use another method to make header not clickable:
.addHeaderView(headerView, null, false);

Answer (score 0):

You could make a "Section 1" to be a part of your list. Just add another type for your customized items list, add "section 1" as first element of your list , and your scrollbar will work as you desired. 
I think that is the most convenient approach.
Regards!